# How to make custom PageManager class for WebPage

Tags: bigcommerce

I have a custom web-page that uses a template in /templates/pages/custom/page/mytemplate.html

Is it possible to create a new PageManager subclass from assets\js\theme\page.js?  Would I need to add this somewhere in assets\js\app.js?

Answer (score 1):

`layouts\base.html`

contains this expression

`window.stencilBootstrap("{{page_type}}", {{jsContext}}).load();`

which is this at runtime

`window.stencilBootstrap("page", {...});`

Values in the global context like these can be used

```
"template_file": "pages/page"
"template": "pages/page"
"settings": { "request": { "absolute_path": "/foo-bar/" } }
```

These can be passed to `function stencilBootstrap` in `assets\js\app.js`, to load a more custom PageManager class.